# Is it possible to make the select dropdown menu open smoother?

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

When I click on the menu on my page, it opens instantly. Is it possible to make it not open immediately, but smoothly, using only CSS and JavaScript?

I've searched StackOverflow and Google for a way to do this, but haven't found a suitable answer.

Comment: It's not possible using the standard `select` control. You would need to find a third party library which converts the `select` element to an editable HTML structure which can have CSS/animation applied to it. I'm not aware of any which has this functionality as standard. As a side note, be very wary of how this behaviour will affect mobile users of your site, and also its accessibility.

Comment: Having a browser control on your site differ from every other website out there will be a frustrating user experience.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, it's not possible to modify that behavior because this is a native HTML element. If you need to have more control you're going to need to switch to a JavaScript based controllers that can emulate the behavior of the `select` element.

There is a lot of non jQuery/jQuery based 3rd party libraries that can help you with that.

### Note

Using those libraries just to implement that behavior is not advised as you will be shipping more JavaScript code to fix something that is noticed only by you. Also those plugins are not necessarily as accessible as the native `select` element.